# Making post-thumbnail a background image

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

My Wordpress site displays all the posts, stacked in articles spanning the full width on the index.php using rows (Bootstrap 3).

index.php - HTML

```
<div>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                get_template_part( 'content' );
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

content.php displays the post in each article (which are stacked on top of each other, full width, down the page)

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?>>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 horiz-cell">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
  </div>    
</div>
</article><!-- /#post -->
```

I have the title and category showing up properly in each row. I would like each post's post-thumbnail (I added its use in functions.php) to be the background image of each row. Filling the  whole space (background-size: cover)

Basically large, '100% width' &  '300px(roughly) height' rows, each with corresponding title, category, and their post-thumbnail as a background-image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If not done yet, enable thumbnails and [define custom image sizes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size):

```
// Enable thumbnails
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
add_image_size('my-fun-size',580, 480, true);
```

To display the thumbnails:
First, get the featured image URL for the post:

*The parameter **'my-fun-size'** should be the name of the size of the image you defined in your functions.php file - it can also be 'full' or 'thumbnail'*

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $thumbnail_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'my-fun-size' );
    $thumbnail_url = $thumbnail_data[0];
}
?>
```

Then add the image as a background:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $thumbnail_url ?>')" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?> >
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 horiz-cell">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
  </div>    
</div>
</article><!-- /#post -->
```

And finally, apply some CSS to achieve your desired background-size:

```
article {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: makes sense, I'm just a bit confused by what you mean in the first part about naming the size of my image in my functions.php. I just added the code to allow for post thumbnails. Also where does that first <?php go? (inside the article or outside?

Comment: If you did not define a custom size for post thumbnails, then you can either omit that argument: `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ) );` or you can specify that the full resolution image should be used: `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'full' );`

Comment: this is prob a dumb question, but I'm just beginning learning Wordpress, how can I define a custom size for post thumbnails, Not sure how important it is seeing that I want them to fill the article

Comment: Updated the answer to include how to set custom image sizes like this: `add_image_size('my-fun-size',580, 480, true);`

Comment: It's working now thank you. I put 'add_image_size('my-fun-size',580, 480, true);' in my functions but I don't think its affecting the image. I removed the 'background-size: cover' from my css but the image is still taking up the full article

Comment: When I upload a smaller image it takes up a certain amount and changing the numeric  values of 'add_image_size('my-fun-size',580, 480, true); ' had no effect

Comment: I apologize, I took a second glance at the link you posted. I didn't know I had to upload the image again to get the sizes to change. Pain in the butt, but it works the way you said. Very much appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've already figured out the CSS part, so here's the PHP/HTML you're looking for:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('container-fluid'); ?>>

  <?php $imgurl = wp_get_attachment_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>

  <div class="row" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $imgurl[0]; ?>');">
    <div class="col-md-12 horiz-cell">
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <?php the_category(', '); ?>
    </div>    
  </div>
</article><!-- /#post -->
```

References:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_thumbnail_id
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src

Comment: where and how do I define wp_get_attachment_src()?

Comment: it is giving me an error 'undefined function wp_get_attachment_src()'

Comment: I used the edited code from the other answer with your code and it seems to work, or at least give me a decent foundation. Cheers!